# Android php insert record prevent DOS attack and csrf attack in multiple submit

Tags: java, php, android, csrf, denial-of-service

1. I am new to android development .I have developed an android app from where one can insert some record via the app to the mysql database using php as server side programming.
2. No need to perform any kind of login operation for inserting the record via the app.
3. So now the problem is that if a user clicks on sumbit button multiple times(say x times) within a fraction of seconds, then same record will be inserted into the database multiple times(x times) ..obviously with different primary key id in each row.
4. So i need to prevent it by generating a unique token in oncreate() and pass the token along with the body post request and validate it at the server end using php.
5. The token must be unique for each post request via app to the server and also it has to be destroyed once it is used for a particular request.
6. So how to go for it? Please help..i need a reference code if anyone can provide..

Comment: Seems like you have a pretty good idea of how to solve this problem. Another way to do it would be to allow only one submit click.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yeah i do have ..but i don't know how to implement it in android and php at the server side

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ok one submit click..that is too possible..ok let me try

Comment: anyone who can help  me out with unique token solution, too..??

Answer (score 0):

A lightweight approach is to generate a token that can self-validate using an HMAC. On the server, you'd generate a token using say `generate_token($secret)` and send this to the client. The client has to include the token in it's response. Validate the token on the server with `valid_token($secret, $token)`.

To prevent re-use of tokens, you have to store the spent tokens. For example, you could store used tokens in a db-record with a unique constraint before proceeding with the request. If inserting fails on the constraint, you know the token was re-used.

Example of token generation and validation:

```
function generate_token($secret) {
  return build_token($secret, bin2hex(random_bytes(5)));
}

function build_token($secret, $id) {
  return $id . '-' . hash_hmac('ripemd160', $id, $secret);
}

function valid_token($secret, $token) {
  $parts = explode('-', $token);
  return $token === build_token($secret, $parts[0]);
}
```

There are other ways. You could generate random ID and store them. Then delete them from the store once they're used. Then you don't need a secret. I prefer storing spent tokens because it's stateless up until the last step.

Edit: Note that to protect against CSRF the token has to include a user-specific ID. In PHP, `session_id()` can often be used for this. A very simplistic approach would concat `session_id()` to `$secret` as in `generate_token($secret . session_id())` and `valid_token($secret . session_id(), $token)`. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: ..thanks for the help..i got your points...will try to implement it